# Eigen value of $ A^{\theta}A $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $n \times n$ nonsingular complex matrix and let $B = A^{\theta}A$ where $A^{\theta} $ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. If $k$ is eigen value of $B$ then what can be said about $k$:

1. $k$ is real or complex?
2. $k <0$ $k \le  0$, $k \ge 0$, $k > 0$. What is true?

My textbook says B is hermetian, so k is real. But why is it hermetian?

Comment: complex conjugate of the the transpose of $A$ is usually denoted by $A^*.$ i have never seen $\theta$ in place of $*$ i almost assumed you were talking about non integer powers of $A$ by looking at the title of your question.

Comment: Theta denotes conjugate transpose

Comment: @abel In linear algebra, the conjugate transpose of $A$ is indeed noted $A^*$, although the notation $A^{\dagger}$ ("A-dagger") is widely used in physics.

Comment: @ketan If an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is hermitian, it satisfies $M^*=M$, where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation followed by transposition. Here, we have that $B=A^*A$, so that $B^*=(A^*A)^*=(A)^*(A^*)^*=A^*A=B$. Therefore $B$ is indeed hermitian. Now, the answers to both your questions follow from the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: @Demosthene thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Let $x$ be an eigenvector for $B$ at eigenvakue $k$. Try to calculate the inner product
$\langle Bx,x\rangle$.